# Client-Side library not found @types/forge-apis and @types/forge-viewer on Visual Studio

Tags: autodesk-forge

Currently, I'm using VS 2019, install package `@types/forge-apis`, and `@types/forge-viewer` on Add Client-Side Library but not found (as pictured below). please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4c4h.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both packages are available on unpkg directly:

- https://unpkg.com/@types/forge-viewer@7.5.2/package.json
- https://unpkg.com/@types/forge-apis@0.7.3/package.json

However, these packages only include TypeScript interfaces, so they are not really "Client-Side Library".

If you are trying to start a new TypeScript project using Autodesk Forge, you will have to install [forge-apis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis), [@types/forge-apis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-apis), and [@types/forge-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-viewer) as **server-side** dependencies.

Comment: In that case you'll need to refer to the libman docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed the library.

Comment: But again, the type definitions and libraries you're trying to install are used for Node.js/TypeScript projects, not for ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core. If you want to start using Forge in ASP.NET Core, take a look at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/netcore for inspiration.